# How to write C++ code that has an "argument out" where the type is not trivially known compile time?

Tags: c++, types, auto

I want to write some templated code that is ready for C++ units. For example, if I compute the square of a quantity that is a float, I will get a float back, but to make the code more general and ready for units, I think I should use auto for the return type, so that metres as input becomes metres squared as output, i.e.

```cpp
template<typename type_base>
auto squared(type_base const vin){
    return vin * vin;
}
```

My question is, if I want to use an "arg out" API, how should this be done? I tried the following, but my compiler complains. Is this expected and should I do something to make my compiler happy? What is the preferred way of doing this?

The example:

```cpp
template<typename type_base>
void squared_2(type_base const & vin, auto & vout){
  vout = vin * vin;
}
```

More generally is there a way to say at compile time that the type of the auto output (example 1) or auto vout (example 2) should be the type of `type_base * type_base`, so that things get even more constrained and that I would detect possible implementations issues in the core of the function at compile time?

Of course, in this case there is no real need for using an arg_out, but my true user case has much heavier types (which are templates on base types that could be units).

Comment: Can you give a practical example of how you finally want to use it?

Comment: For now I want to use this when computing the norm of a 3D vector. I.e., something very similar to these 2 examples, except that the args would be some ```Vector3<type_base>``` and the functions would be called ```norm_squared```. But I think including these details in the question makes it a bit too specific.

Comment: You can also try to abstract that, as you did with your template definitions? [Mcve] would be ideal.

Comment: What does "_to make the code more general and ready for units_" mean? What are "_units_" in this context?

Comment: Mmmh, I am not sure that I understand what this means? :)

Comment: First you forgot the return value `void` and second the out parameter is better (https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f20-for-out-output-values-prefer-return-values-to-output-parameters). If you still want it, you need a second template parameter (typename TResult, then TResult& vout).

Comment: I want to be ready for this kind of things that are on their way to the standard: https://github.com/mpusz/units . I.e., an acceleration vector is not of type (float, float, float), but of type (meters_per_seconds_squared, meters_per_seconds_squared, meters_per_seconds_squared), and the squared norm of it is of type meters_per_seconds_squared**2 or whatever its name.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the forgotten void, fixed now. Well, I need to write some code for MCUs, and I would like to avoid creating objects as much as possible...

Comment: @Zorglub29 Many cases of object creation are optimized by the compiler. Look at this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision. And even more complicated cases can be very efficient if you object support move semantic.

Comment: If you want an example of how to operate with units, you can read chapter  8 (point 28.7) from the book "The C++ programming language" by Stroustrup.

Answer (score 2):

You can use decltype to determine the result of the product in a way like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename type_base>
void squared_2(type_base const & vin, decltype(vin*vin) & vout){
    vout = vin * vin;
}


int main()
{
    double a;
    squared_2(5.,a);
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Aaah, thanks, I was not aware of this. Will look at decltype in more details :) .